# How to prevent public viewing of your GA Property ID

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to protect the data integrity of a client's Google Analytics information.   In installing the javascript, you include your Property ID (UA-xxxxxxx-x) to send the information to Google.   Is there a way to abstract this from viewers who view the page source?

I know that you can create a filter in the GA web viewer ([read up on it here](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/protect-analytics-from-hacking/)), but I was wanting to know if anyone has tried to completely prevent the viewing of the number, and if so, how?

Comment: This is not possible, nor necessary.

Comment: In theory you could set up a server to capture the user data and send it yourself to the google tracker but it is a lot of work and for no payout. No need to hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Diodeus is correct.

If you're worried about people sending information to your profile, you should setup filters to only include traffic on domains you own.

[Google Analytics: About profile filters](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033162)

Answer (score 6):

You can't. If the public can't see it, Google can't see it either. Google needs this number to track everything.